# Deleting a record without deleting related records in another Access table

Tags: winforms, ms-access, ms-access-2007, c#-2.0

I have enabled Referential Integrity in Access 2007. I want to delete a customer record from customer table but want to keep related bill details of that particular customer in another table called bill table. When I try to delete a customer record I get an error message: "The record cannot be deleted or changed because table 'bill' includes related records".

Comment: I don't know your business rules, but deleting a customer record that has bill details seems to be clearly wrong. What about a flag field in the customer table to mark the customer as logically deleted?

Comment: I am developing a "gym management system". when a customer gets discontinued i want to delete the personal data but not his receipt/bill paid details.

Comment: Then remove the cascade relationship on delete. Still this is illogical. If, what you ask could be done, how do you know to which customer those billing details refers to?

Comment: yes steve its illogical. But thank you very much i could use flag field method.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have it both ways: You can either have Referential Integrity enforced, or you can allow orphaned child records to be created when the parent record is deleted (i.e., by disabling the enforcement of Referential Integrity).

As mentioned in the comment to your question, you *could* add a `Yes/No` field named [Inactive] or [Deleted] to the parent table and then use queries that only consider "active" parent records, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM [Customer] WHERE NOT [Inactive]
```

Another possibility is to have a separate "archive" database to store deleted items. You copy all related records (parent and child) to the archive database and then delete them (child first, then parent) from the main database.